# SQL join issue to retrieve from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following 3  tables in my sql

```
1. person table

user_id active  email           fullName        joined              password
bucky   1       bucky@abc.com   Bucky Wall      1/30/2017 12:43:46  bucky
james   1       james@abc.com   James Goedic    1/30/2017 12:43:19  james
praveen 1       praveen@abc.com Praveen Reddy S 1/30/2017 12:37:40  praveen
priya   1       priya@abc.com   Priya Reddy     1/10/2017 10:30:17  priya

2. tweet table

tweet_id    created             message                         user_id
 1        1/30/2017 12:45:37    @Bucky!. Meet me in office      james
 2        1/30/2017 12:45:58    @James!. How nare you?          praveen
 3        1/30/2017 12:46:10    Hi, Every One                   praveen
 4        1/30/2017 12:46:38    @James: Hellow James            bucky
 5        1/31/2017 10:30:50    This is Priya                   priya


 3. following table

 user_id        following_id
 praveen         bucky
 praveen        james
```

Now I want to retrive messages of a user praveen and his assigned following users bucky and james. praveen user have two messages and bucky has one message and james have one message. total 4 messages i want to display.

I tried flowing query and its not working. Help me to get right query

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tweet t
WHERE
    t.user_id = (SELECT 
            f.user_id
        FROM
            following f
        WHERE
            f.following_id = f.user_id)
        OR t.user_id = 'praveen'
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use in to compare multiple usserID and you want to following people name,so you should select following_id to get its data. and in where condition you should write `user_id='praveen'`

```
  SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        tweet t
    WHERE
        t.user_id in (SELECT 
                f.following_id
            FROM
                following f
            WHERE
                f.user_id ='praveen')
            OR t.user_id = 'praveen'
```

Comment: Perfect ! . your query working perfectly. Thank you very much . You have saved my day .

Comment: If I want to display the messages of users who are following only praveen, then i should remove last or condition right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using joins

```
    SELECT 
        message,tweet_id,user_id
    FROM
        tweet t,person p,following f
    WHERE
    t.user_id=p.user_id and f.user_id=p.user_id and t.user_id = 'praveen'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    message
FROM
    tweet t INNER JOIN following f ON t.user_id = f.user_id or t.user_id = f.following_id
WHERE
    t.user_id = 'praveen' and f.following_id in ('bucky','james')
```

Comment: he will not have following_id name. so make your ans correct